# Update dynamic entity with OData V4 client

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-crm

Trying to update an entity property with OData v4 client, somehow get this error:

xxx_accountid is navigation property, but I didn't update this property, its type is nullable.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Property _xxx_accountid_value cannot be updated to null. The reference property can only be deleted.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "Property _xxx_accountid_value cannot be updated to null. The reference property can only be deleted.",
      "type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",
      "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataUtilities.ValidatePatchInputProperties(EdmEntityObject entityDelta)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PatchEntity(String entityName, String key, EdmEntityObject entityDelta)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n "
    }
  }
}
```

Resolved. It turns out the _xxx_accountid is a navigation property generated by CRM itself. I deleted this property in T4 template and it worked.

Comment: Are you using Logic apps or Flow? Can we see your code as well ?

Answer (score 3):

As it is said in the error

> The reference property can only be deleted

It is not possible to set `Lookup` to null in the update call (this is strange, but it is so)

you can clean up the references by calling `DELETE` of a reference property of an object

```
/api/data/v8.2/contacts([ID])/xxx_accountid/$ref
// instead of contacts set changed entity
```

[Details about remove reference request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607875.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks, @Aspirin. This is useful. It turns out the _xxx_accountid is a navigation property used by CRM itself. I deleted this property in T4 template and it worked.